# Cascading hydrate with DoctrineHydrator

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it possible?

```
    $hydrator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('DoctrineHydrator');
    $hydrator->hydrate((array) $data, $PlatformEntity);
```

Hydrator hydrate only 1 level of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array hydration is not the best way for achieve this kind of situations. The same scenario here:

```
Person
  - id_person
  - name
  - child //self refering
```

Array hydration only select the first level. I resolving it taking one of these two options:

1. Use `left join` association

   ```
   $query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6')
   ->from('Entity\Person', 'p1')
   ->leftJoin('p1.child', 'p2')
   ->leftJoin('p2.child', 'p3')
   ->leftJoin('p3.child', 'p4')
   ->leftJoin('p4.child', 'p5')
   ->leftJoin('p5.child', 'p6')
   ->createQuery();
   ```

   and then, use array hydration.
2. Create your own recursive function in order to add manually each element in an array.